# Is it possible to use the Wacom Wireless Accessory Kit on an Intuos4 L?

Tags: graphics-tablet

Is it possible to use the Wacom Wireless Accessory Kit on an Intuos4 L (PTK-840-xx)?

http://www.wacom.com/en/products/accessories/wireless/wireless-accessory-kit

I am not asking for a hint, that Wacom does not specify this! Wacom does specify it amongst others, for a Intuos5 L (PTH-850-xx). But I could not find any Info, that it does **not** work with an Intuos4 L.

I am asking, if some has actually tried this or would be so kind to try it, if he has the possibillity.

Comment: Are you just wondering or is this a problem you are actually experiencing?

Comment: Would like to order one for my Intuos4 L - of course, just if it works. I might buy it anyways and provide the answer myself, but I would rather like to confirm an positive answer ;)

Comment: That makes sense to ask that before you buy. Unfortunately, it does not follow the guidelines in the [faq] for asking "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". I would suggest contacting Wacom directly.

Comment: I get your point, although one could argue, that i am facing an actual problem, which is quite easy and practical to answer - just not for me, as i don't have this hardware. But I am sure, many Intuos4 users would appreciate an answer, as would I. There seems to be nothing on the web, at least not to be easy found or a 100% proof/disproof.

Comment: That makes sense and is why I have not marked it to be closed. It is a good question. To improve it, and to avoid soliciting opinion, might I suggest removing the last line of your post? You obviously want answers to your question and not replies to your opinion. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot.

The Wireless Accessory Kit only fits the latest-generation Wacom tablets, including the Bamboo Capture, Bamboo Create, and Intuos5 series.  While there was once a variant of the Intuos4 tablets with Bluetooth-based wireless capability, these tablets do not accept the Wireless Accessory Kit.

Comment: good thing I baugth the accessory kit instead :) thanks!